# Isn't a constant validation key a security risk?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken, machinekey

Today I learned that on server farms, I must not use `validationKey="AutoGenerate"`, but specify a 'fixed' string value for `validationKey`, for consistency across request handling by the farm servers. The example given was:

```
<machineKey  
validationKey="21F090935F6E49C2C797F69BBAAD8402ABD2EE0B667A8B44EA7DD4374267A75D7
               AD972A119482D15A4127461DB1DC347C1A63AE5F1CCFAACFF1B72A7F0A281B"           
decryptionKey="ABAA84D7EC4BB56D75D217CECFFB9628809BDB8BF91CFCD64568A145BE59719F"
validation="SHA1"
decryption="AES"
/>
```

I was under the impression that the generation of a new key for every request and every user enhanced security quite a bit, but if the key is constant, it be retrieved from the hidden field on a form and used in a forged request.

Or must I cease using hidden fields for this key when on a server farm and use a header or cookie instead?

I say the anti-forgery key is stored in the form because this Razor markup:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

renders this HTML:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="bH6_-oZcRMuC9tA13RrOzmr0N3sWrzgkjKOhg2igHs5K2-G0HbJbF3KaK-QMrUDcQTXFbHJ-HFMNn9AjvF-TkAuBFo5f8Afi8q0OHXBzOTI1">
```

Unless we are talking about different keys here, but how would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a security risk.

The autogenerated key is not sent in a hidden field in the form, it's stored in the Local Security Authority (LSA) on the server ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). If the key was sent in the form then there would be no need to have the same key on multiple servers. There would also not be any need to retrieve a key to forge a request, you could just send whatever key you wanted in a request.

With autogeneration the server doesn't generate a new key for each request, it generates a key for the server (or for the application if the `IsolateApps` option is used). It's only the message authentication code (MAC) that is generated for each request.

Comment: @ProfK: They are different. The anti forgery token is not the encryption key, it's a request specific token that is encrypted using the key. The encryption key never leaves the server.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I think the request once is called a MAC. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218 Thanks for the info.